# group by in queries that contains subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, conditional-aggregation

How can I group by the following query by customerId

```
select
(SELECT SUM(Purchase) FROM Customers where type in (17,21)) as 'Purchase'
,(SELECT SUM(Point) FROM Customers) as 'Point'
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just want conditional aggregation, which you can do by placing `CASE WHEN...` inside a `SUM`.

```sql
SELECT
  c.CustomerId
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.type IN (17, 21) THEN c.Purchase END) AS Purchase,
  SUM(c.Point) AS Point
FROM CUSTOMERS c
GROUP BY
  c.CustomerID;
```

Note the use of a table alias to make it more readable, and do not use `''` to quote column names, only `[]` and only where necessary.

Comment: Neat. I like the use of conditional aggregation

Comment: I don't think using a table alias makes a query more readable which selects from one table only.

Comment: Matter of taste I guess

Answer (score 0):

Remove the From Customers in the Selects and Move the Where to the root of the query

Change your query to

```
SELECT
[CustomerID] as 'CustomerID'
, SUM([Purchase]) as 'Purchase'
, SUM([Point]) as 'Point'
FROM [CUSTOMERS]
WHERE [type] in (17,21)
GROUP BY [Customers].[CustomerID]
```

This will give you

```
CustomerID  Purchase    Point
1           246         3
2           23434       7
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to get the total *Purchase* and total *Points* per customer, then you need to include the CustomerId in the *Purchase* sub-query as well as in your main query.

A key thing to remember regarding Group By is that all non-aggregate columns have to be included in it. Therefore in your case, you'd have to group by the *Purchase* as well.

Your final query would look like:

```
select c.CustomerId, 
(SELECT SUM(Purchase) FROM Customers where type in (17,21) and CustomerId = c.CustomerId) as 'Purchase'
, SUM(Point) as 'Point'
FROM CUSTOMERS c
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, Purchase
```

Comment: But why bother with the subquery at all? Why *not* use conditional aggregation, it's a standard technique? Also you don't need to and probably should not group by `Purchase` as it isn't used in the `SELECT`, the only mention of `Purchase` refers to the *subquery's* `Purchase` column.

Comment: I take it you missed my comment on your answer :)

Comment: I didn't miss it, I just don't get why you would even consider the above, as mentioned. I just mean: isn't obvious that OP wants conditional aggregation?